# How to query fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to do some query with fields mapping but it not working.

define index mapping

```
english_mapping = {
 "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "english": { 
            "type":     "text",
            "analyzer": "english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

es.indices.create(index = 'english', body = english_mapping)
```

add some data

```
doc2 = { "text": "quick brown fox" }
doc3 = { "text": "quick brown foxes" }
es.index(index='english', document = doc2, id = 1)
es.index(index='english', document = doc3, id = 2)
```

query on text.english field but it not working (it return both document)

```
res = es.search(index = 'english',  body = {"query": {
    "match": {
        "text.english" : "foxes"
    }
}})
```

Please help me how to query on text.english field.

Comment: By "it's not working" you mean that both documents return and you expect only the second one to return?

Comment: When reproducing your example above, I get the two documents in the results, which is the correct behavior

Comment: Sorry, please help me check again, i expected result is empty, because i use english analyzer it cause foxes replace to fox, than the query should return empty

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The [`english` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) you're using is composed of an [`english_stemmer` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html), and what this does is stemming words, like for instance `foxes` gets' stemmed to `fox`.

Hence, both of your documents below get analyzed/stemmed the same way

```
doc2 = { "text": "quick brown fox" }
doc3 = { "text": "quick brown foxes" }
```

i.e. the following tokens get indexed: `quick`, `brown` and `fox`.

Same thing at search time when searching for `foxes`, it's gets analyzed to `fox` and that's the reason why it finds both documents.

If you search on the `text` field instead of `text.english`, the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used instead and no stemming occurs, so it will work as you expect.